# User ownership of table that can reference multiple users

Tags: laravel

I have a small application which has 2 migrations, team and team_user (it also has the default auth migrations).
The teams & default user migration has a **belongsToMany** relationship. As of now, everyone has the same relationship to each team. What would be a good elegant way to create ownership to the team as a sort of Team Leader. I'm currently exploring creating an additional team_leader migration but not sure if that's the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a team only has one lead you could add a `team_lead_id` column on the `teams` table that is a foreign key reference to the team lead user.  Then you could define the relationship on the Team model:

```
public function leader()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In the case of multiple leads per team then you'd need a pivot table like the team_leader table you mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much, That makes a lot of sense.